# Java - Can't see JRadioButtons

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I am a beginner and I was practicing JRadioButtons. I realised that **I can't see my JRadioButtons if I'll not set my layout as `'FlowLayout()'`**. I want to set the location of the buttons by myself.

I posted my code below, can anyone help me **what am I doing wrong**?

Thanks!

```
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JRadioButton btn1, btn2;


public JBButtons() {

    form();
    radioButtons();

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void form(){

    frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    //panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}


public void radioButtons() {

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

    btn1 = new JRadioButton("btn1");
    btn1.setSelected(true);
    btn1.setLocation(50, 50);

    btn2 = new JRadioButton("btn2");
    btn2.setLocation(50, 70);

    group.add(btn1);
    group.add(btn2);

    panel.add(btn1);
    panel.add(btn2);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new JBButtons();
}
```

Comment: The code you added in `JBButton()` method should be added in the main, as the program starts by running main.

Comment: that was the constructor method actually but It just didn't appear in here.  Hopefully @Alok Shinha opened my eyes, the only thing I haven't done is setting sizes for the buttons! :)

Comment: @aiox, `I want to set the location of the buttons by myself.` - Don't use a null layout!!! Swing was designed to be used with layout managers (for too many reasons to list here). Learn to use Swing the was it was designed to be used. There are always ways to give suggestions to the proper layout manager to position the component as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with absolute positioning or null layout is - it requires you to set the sizes of all your components, otherwise they will stay their default zero-size and won't show up. Better use a layout manager - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: oh wow, I literally forgot to set sizes for these buttons...  I am sure that setBounds() will work perfectly fine then. Thank you!!!

Comment: @aiox No, that’s not what Alok was telling you.  Don’t set sizes or positions.  Use the correct LayoutManager instead.  The way you’re doing it, other computers will have different display characteristics and your buttons will not look right.

Answer (score 0):

Add this part of the code when adding the RadioButton to the panel, use the property `.setBounds(x, y, width, heigth)`.

```
panel.add(btn1);
btn1.setBounds(90, 59, 93, 23);
panel.add(btn2);
btn2.setBounds(180, 60, 93, 23);
```